# Eclipse Erlide how to choose default current directory

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I have installed Erlide in Eclipse, and trying to create an application. The Erlang project is named **demo**. It contains three folders - **ebin**, **include** and **src**. The `demo.erl` file is in `src`, for simply printing **Hello World**.

To run it in Eclipse shell, I choose **Run** from the top menu, and click **Run as Erlang Application**. Then a console opens in the sidebar. There I type **c(demo)** and press `CTRL-Enter`. Then I get an error message like **demo.erl:none: no such file or directory**.

Then I do `pwd()`, and it shows **C:/Users/myName/Desktop/eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64/eclipse** even though the Erlang project is in workspace **C:/Users/myName/Desktop/workspace/Erlang**. Is there any way make Erlide run all Erlang applications from their directory directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you have set *Project* -> *Build Automatically* in Eclipse to true, you don't need to type *c(demo).* explicitly to compile the demo module, it's done automatically when you save your file. But if you have not set it, you'll get *exception error: undefined function* if you try to use some of the functions in the module for example.

To make the *c(demo)* command work properly and find your .erl files, there are several ways to set the current working directory:

1. Use *Run* -> *Run Configuration* -> *Erlang Application* -> *Runtimes* -> *Working directory* -> enter the full path to the /*src* folder of your project (without quotes).
   Then hit *Apply* and restart Eclipse (*File* -> *Restart*). If you try to *Run* the project without first restarting the IDE, your changes will not take effect i.e. the *pwd().* command will still be returning the old working directory path.
2. You can set the working directory in the erlide console with the command *c:cd(the/full/path/to/your/src/folder).*, before the call to *c(demo)*. The path should be put in quotes.
3. You can also set the working directory in the *.erlang* file by typing there the same command *c:cd(the/full/path/to/your/src/folder).* (the path again should be put in quotes). The file must be placed in you user directory, for Windows this would be *C:/Documents and Settings/YourUsername*. It's the same directory were also *.erlang.cookie* and *erlide-debug.txt* are placed. Windows Explorer will not allow you to create a file named *.erlang*, so you have to use the command *copy NUL .erlang* in Command Prompt *(cmd.exe)* for this. Then you can edit it with any txt redactor. Don't forget to restart Eclipse again after it.

Also note the following:

1. You can use only / and not \ in the path (even in Windows).
2. If you have entered a wrong path (with \ or to a non existing directory), it will be ignored and the working directory will not be changed at all.
3. After changing the working directory to your/*src* folder, your beam files will start to appear there too instead of the /*ebin* folder.
4. If you set a different path in both *.erlang* file and *Run -> Run Configuration -> Erlang Application -> Runtimes -> Working directory*, pwd(). will return the path in .erlang file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run c(demo). The beam code is loaded and reloaded automatically,  whenever the source is changed and saved.

If you still need to set a working directory, go to run->run configuration and you can edit the configuration.

/Vlad